# Differentiating a constant and switching order

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Why does this work?

$$\int x^2e^{ax}dx = \int \frac{d^2}{da^2}e^{ax}dx = \frac{d^2}{da^2}\int e^{ax}dx = \frac {d^2}{da^2} \frac {e^{ax}}a = \frac{e^{ax}(a^2x^2-2ax+2)}{a^3}$$

$a$ is a constant, so how can you take the derivative with respect to it?  Also, why can you just switch the order of integration with differentiation?  We did this is physics, but what's the justification?  Will this type of thing always work?

Comment: Usually in physics you do not need any justification if it works.

Comment: @Jihad I am a physics student your statement is definitely true but does that help the OP? ;)

Comment: This was one of Feynman's favorite tricks.  See [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) for a full explanation.

Comment: @Jihad I've noticed.  But I was wondering anyway. :)

Comment: @vadim123 Thanks for the link -- I didn't know what this technique was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physicists love doing this. I would not hesitate in saying this almost always works. You are right that $a$ is a constant but it is also true that if $a$ were treated as a variable, the statement $$ x^2 e^{ax} = \frac {\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}a^2} e^{ax} $$ is true. As for differentiating under the integral sign, see a full explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).